# How to install Ubuntu on another windows partition other than /C: without cd or usb

Tags: 14.04

I'm trying to install ubuntu on another partition on my windows drive using unetbootin, but no avail.

Can anyone explain how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. You need to make a bootable USB or CD and install from that.